# Use ts-select2 in Rails with importmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I am trying to install [ts-select2](https://github.com/ivkan/ts-select2) in a Rails 7 App.

I ran:

```
./bin/importmap pin ts-select2
```

And it added this line to config/importmap.rb

```
pin "ts-select2", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:ts-select2@0.2.5/dist/ts-select2.min.js"
```

My example in application.js

```
import 'ts-select2'

const select2 = new TsSelect2(document.getElementById('user_groups'), {minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity, width: `250px`});
```

Browser gives error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TsSelect2 is not defined
```